# React - Functional split page

Tags: css, reactjs, flexbox

I am a beginner in React and I would like to show two different things in my project but on the same page: I want to split the screen in 2 and achieve this (example: left side -> I want to show a map which is functional; right side -> I want to show a video). Also, how should I organize the files inside my React project? [example picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tP658.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to style it in CSS. The container permit to have the two components in a line, then you tell that each component as a 50% width

JS:

```js
<div className='container'> 
  <div className='map'>
    <Map />
  </div> 
  <div className='video'>
    <Video />
  </div> 
</div>
```

CSS :

```css
.container {
  display : flex;
  flex-direction : row;
  width: 100%;
}

.map {
  width: 50%;
}

.video {
  width: 50%;
}
```